# \\selectlanguage{} cumulates word spacings in non-normalsize environments

Tags: luatex, fontspec, babel

The following MWE shows an effect where the word spacing in non-normalsize-d text blocks "grows" with every `\selectlanguage` that introduces a previously unused language (using lualatex):

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book}

\usepackage[main=german,bidi=basic]{babel}
\babelprovide[import]{english}
\babelprovide[import]{french}
\babelprovide[import]{portuguese}
\babelfont{rm}[%
  WordSpace = 1.5
]{texgyrepagella-regular.otf}
\parindent0pt
\parskip.5\baselineskip

\def\test#1{%
\selectlanguage{#1}%
normal normal normal normal normal normal normal normal normal normal normal normal normal normal normal normal normal normal normal normal normal normal normal\par
\bgroup\small
 small small small small small small small small small small small small small small small small small small small small small small small small small small small small
\egroup\par}
\def\Test{%
\test{german}
\test{english}
%% un-comment the following two lines to strengthen the effect and observe the results after the FIRST lualatex run, and after CONSECUTIVE lualatex runs!
%\test{french}
%\test{portuguese}
}
\begin{document}

\Test
\Test
\Test
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image: render result showing narrower word spacing in first small block than in the following blocks]

(Note the spacing in the second "small" block compared to the first one.)

The effect is even stronger when the `\test{french}` and `\test{portuguese}` lines are uncommented in the definition of `\Test`.  Also note that the rendering result of the normal text is different after the first run, compared to the second run after those lines are un-commented.

This effect is visible in texlive2019 installed from CTAN sources in June 2019, in texlive2019 installed in February 2020, and in texlive2020 installed in October 2020.

My question is: Is there a local fix to that issue without updating texlive and/or the babel package? I need to get it to run in the earlier texlive 2019 version since this is the texlive that runs on an active production machine.

Comment: well babel setups fonts language dependant, and WordSpace is a setting that adds a factor and when you combine this you get larger settings. If you don't need the language dependency you could use fontspec and \setmainfont instead to declare the font.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do need the languages. Many of them… (i mean languages that under circumstances may use non.latin script systems)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could reproduce the problem without `babel`, so it seems a bug in `fontspec`, or at least an unexpected behavior. A possible workaround is to make sure `WordSpace` is executed only once:

```
\babelfont{rm}[WordSpace = 1.5]{texgyrepagella-regular.otf}
\babelfont[english, french, portuguese, german]{rm}{texgyrepagella-regular.otf}
```

In this particular example it works for me.

Comment: Does this mean that the wider WordSpace is only applied in the main language parts?

Comment: @Lupino No, the underlying issue is that fontspec applies WordSpace in a way that it always affects all fonts which are identical, so since the main language, english, frensh, portugese, german, ... fonts are the same (the font does not have any font specific features), they will all get WordSpace. Of course, this depends on a bug so it *will* break once that bug is fixed.

Comment: Is there a macro where the list of `\babelprovide`'d languages are stored?

Comment: @Lupino In recent versions there is a macro named `\LocaleForEach`. You can use it to traverse the list of the locales loaded.

Comment: @MarcelKrüger There is a similar issue with `HyphenChar`. See https://github.com/latex3/babel/blob/master/news-guides/news/whats-new-in-babel-3.46.md#getting-rid-of-hyphens-in-xetex

Comment: @JavierBezos Except maybe for HyphenChar=None which is special anyway that shouldn't affect LuaTeX though, or does it?